# Extracting archives of multiple types

Tags: python

Is there any module in *Python*, which lets me extract a variety of archives? I need to extract *zip*, *tar.bz2*, *tar.z*, *rar* and others.
Right now it looks like I have to do the archive type detection manually and also to write an extraction for every single one.

Pure *Python* would be prefered.

Comment: I know rar, zip and tar have Pythonic interfaces that work like the `tarfile` module. The others, I'm not sure about.

Comment: No there is not. You can do zip with `import zipfile` and tar using `import tarfile` but `rar` does not exist and others will be sketchy.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Patool](http://wummel.github.io/patool/).  I can't attest to how well it works, but there are a few other modules based off of it, though it does depend on external applications for some formats.

> patool supports 7z (.7z), ACE (.ace), ADF (.adf), ALZIP (.alz), APE (.ape), AR (.a), ARC (.arc), ARJ (.arj), BZIP2 (.bz2), CAB (.cab), COMPRESS (.Z), CPIO (.cpio), DEB (.deb), DMS (.dms), FLAC (.flac), GZIP (.gz), LRZIP (.lrz), LZH (.lha, .lzh), LZIP (.lz), LZMA (.lzma), LZOP (.lzo), RPM (.rpm), RAR (.rar), RZIP (.rz), SHN (.shn), TAR (.tar), XZ (.xz), ZIP (.zip, .jar) and ZOO (.zoo) formats. It relies on helper applications to handle those archive formats (for example bzip2 for BZIP2 archives).

Answer (score 1):

In the standard library, you already have modules `zlib`, `gzip`, `bz2`, `zipfile` and `tarfile` to work with compressed archives.

For rar archives, there is the [rarfile module on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/2.2) that has a similar interface to zipfile and works with python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.2 it looks like `shutil` is [adding more archiving functionality](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#shutil), but so far only gziptar, bztar, tar and zip are supported.

You can add your own handlers with `shutil.register_archive_format()`- this way you wouldn't have to detect the extension manually...but you'd still need to define the extraction yourself.

Answer (score 1):

this thread is old but I ran into this problem again.
I have tried Patool option or pyunpack (which relies on Patool) but would highly recommend *not* to use a Patool-based option and go for the builtin shutil lib as Patool seems to be [unsupported for some time now](https://github.com/wummel/patool/issues/58). I myself [ran into a bug](https://github.com/wummel/patool/issues/90) because of a changed lib name.

As [crennie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19640648/7541501) answered, I went for the high-level builtin shutil lib, and below is my code to add 7z and rar formats to shutil capabilities which is the full initial question.
Note that this requires `p7zip-full` and `p7zip-rar` which can be easily setup with a `pip install` :

```
def extractfiles(zipname, output_dir):
    """Extract files with 7z utils.

    -aoa switch asks for automatic overwrite without prompting user.
    """
    logging.info(f"Extracting {zipname} to {output_dir}")
    pipe = Popen(["7z", "x", "-aoa", "-bd", zipname, f"-o{output_dir}"], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
    return(pipe.communicate())


def register_extensions():
    """Register additionnal archive formats supported by 7zip in shutil."""
    shutil.register_unpack_format('rar', ['.rar', '.RAR'], extractfiles)
    shutil.register_unpack_format('7z', ['.7z', '.7Z'], extractfiles)
```

Comment: I believe you should use [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) in modern Python rather than Popen() for running subprocesses such as 7z.

Comment: As of September 2023 it looks like the patool repo has several fairly recent commits and pull requests that are merged.